# can we set cubism.js y-axis no up limit?

Tags: javascript, html, cubism.js

I am using `cubism.js` to show my data, but my data do not have up limit, or my data will change a lot.

Please help me!

```
div.append("div")
  .attr("class", "horizon")
  .call(context.horizon()
  .height(240)
  .mode("offset")
  .colors(["#08519c","#3182bd"])
  .title("QPS")
  .extent([0, ???]));
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try using the Number.MAX_VALUE:

```
div.append("div")
  .attr("class", "horizon")
  .call(context.horizon()
  .height(240)
  .mode("offset")
  .colors(["#08519c","#3182bd"])
  .title("QPS")
  .extent([0, Number.MAX_VALUE]));
```